# React - Passing information into a component, rendering as null

Tags: reactjs

I've somehow broke my working React code, and I can't figure out why. I'm new to learning React and so far all my attempts to fix it have gone unfounded and it's possible I've made it worse.

I have 4 "menu" cards. When you click on a menu card, a new card pops up on the bottom left with some additional info on that menu item, as well as comments about the menu item on the bottom right.

I have a DishDetail component that renders that selectedDish information. The component mounts and renders, but my dishdetail renders null

My main component renders the Menu component and dishdetail component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
    };
  }

  //sets the state of the selected Dish
  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
  }

  //Renders the page with all its subcomponents
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) => this.onDishSelect(dishId)} />
        <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

The menu component renders the 4 menu cards

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

    function RenderMenuItem({ dish, onClick }) {
        return(
            <Card key={dish.id}
                onClick={() => props.onClick(dish.id)}>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
        );
    }

    const Menu = (props) => {

        const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
              <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} onClick={props.onClick} />
              </div>
            );
        });

        //then returns a container of the menu
        return (
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row">
                  {menu}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
    }
        

        

export default Menu;
```

The dishdetail component is supposed to render the menu/dish item information

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 
'reactstrap';

    function RenderDish({dish}) {
        if (dish != null)
            return(
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
                </div>
            );
        else
            return(
                <div>For Some Reason, dish is null</div>
            );
    }

    function RenderComments({comments}){
        if (comments != null){
            const coms = comments.map((com) => {
                return(
                    <ul key={com.id} className='list-unstyled'>
                        <li>
                            {com.comment}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            -- {com.author}, { }
                            {
                                new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
                                    month: 'short', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' 
                                }).format(new Date(com.date))
                            }
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                );
            });
            return(
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>Comments</h4>
                    {coms}
                </div>
            );}
        else{
            return(
                <div>For Some reason, comments are null</div>
            );
            }

    }


    const DishDetail = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
                    <RenderComments comments={props.comments} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }


export default DishDetail;
```

Theres also a file that contains the information for all the individual menu items.

```
export const DISHES =
[
    {
    id: 0,
    name:'Uthappizza',
    image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    label:'Hot',
    price:'4.99',
    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]                        },
    {
    id: 1,
    name:'Zucchipakoda',
    image: 'assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label:'',
    price:'1.99',
    description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name:'Vadonut',
    image: 'assets/images/vadonut.png',
    category: 'appetizer',
    label:'New',
    price:'1.99',
    description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
    image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
    category: 'dessert',
    label:'',
    price:'2.99',
    description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
    comments: [
        {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        },
        {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
        }
    ]
    }
];
```

I think the break is somewhere between the dishId and passing that information to the dishdetail component, but I don't quite understand why. I'm new to React so I'm having a hard time visualizing/troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1):

you're destructuring the onClick prop on the RenderMenuItem component and trying to reference props.onClick

Answer (score 1):

```
Fixes are given below.

1. `props.onClick` to `onClick`.

function RenderMenuItem({ dish, onClick }) {
  return (
    <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
      <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
      <CardImgOverlay>
        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
      </CardImgOverlay>
    </Card>
  );

2. `props.comments` to `props.dish.comments`. To avoid first time invalid access of empty `dish` object for comments insert `null` check.

const DishDetail = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
        {props.dish != null && (
          <RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1. To solve the issue with the non-rendering card, you need to remove "props." from the onClick. It is no longer needed when the props are defined in the function;

```
...

function RenderMenuItem({ dish, onClick }) {
        return(
            <Card key={dish.id}
                onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
        );
    }

...
```

1. To solve the issue of the missing comment section, you need to reference the props of the parent dish before the comments in the DishDetail function;
   "props.comments" should be "props.dish.comments" (Edit: This worked temporarily and no longer is working though I'm not sure why. If I make this change the comments show up until the page is refreshed and it says "props.dish is undefined".)

```
...

    const DishDetail = (props) => {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
                    <RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

...
```